# Ordering Child Table data using JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am creating dynamic data and displayed in child table using DOM object. This is the child table detail.

```
<table id="stdConTbl" width="135px" height="80px" class = "stdConTbl">

</table>
```

This is the code to create dynamic tr data.

```
var tbody = document.getElementById("stdConTbl").tBodies[0];
    var tr = document.createElement('tr');
    var td = document.createElement('td');
    var att = document.createAttribute("width");
    att.value = "1%";
    td.setAttributeNode(att);
    var td1 = document.createElement('td');
    td.innerHTML = '<input type = "radio" style = "BACKGROUND-COLOR: #e1e8ee" id = "' + tmpCount + '" name = "' + radioName + '" value = "' + txtValue + '" onclick = "setTblRowId()"/>';
    td1.innerHTML = '<label id = '+ tmpCount +"'>" +txtValue + '</label>';
    tr.appendChild(td);
    tr.appendChild(td1);
    //var radioHtml = tr.innerHTML;
    tbody.appendChild(tr);
```

Using this two button I am ordering these table data.

```
<img src="<%=request.getContextPath()%>/images/procseq/up.png" style="cursor: hand;" class="up" />
<img src="<%=request.getContextPath()%>/images/procseq/down.png" style="cursor: hand;" class="down" />
```

When i choosing this dynamically created radio button and click on "UP" button, the selected radio button label should be move one step to up and again i click on "UP" button the label should move one more step.

Same thing i follow when i click on "DOWN" button.

But I am not able to get child table row index.

This the code to order data.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$(".up,.down").click(function(){
    var selectedIndex = 0;
    //var row = $(this).parents("tr:first"),$reindex_start;
    for(var i = 0; i < document.getElementsByName('stdConRadio').length; i++){
        if(document.getElementsByName('stdConRadio')[i].checked){
            selectedIndex = document.getElementsByName('stdConRadio')[i].getAttribute("id");
        }
    }
    var row = $(this).parents(".stdConTbl"),$reindex_start;
    //var row_index = $(this).closest('tr').index();        
    if ($(this).is(".up")) {            
        //row.insertBefore(selectedIndex - 1);
        row.insertBefore(row.prev());
        $reindex_start=row;
    } else {
        $reindex_start=row.next();          
        row.insertAfter(row.next());
    }
});
```

});

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this : find `tr` of the the selected radio button and then use `insertAfter` or `insertBefore` to move `tr`.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(".up,.down").click(function(){
    //get tr of selected radio button
    var $tr = $('#stdConTbl').find('input[name="stdConRadio"]:checked').closest("tr");
    //insert 
    if ($(this).is(".up")) {            
        $tr.insertBefore($tr.prev("tr"));
    } else {        
        $tr.insertAfter($tr.next("tr"));
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: happy to help you :)